# Pass environment variables on compilation phase

Tags: crystal-lang

In development i need to test console utility with server environment variables. Is there a way pass the environment variables and compile utility as if it were running on a server?

Something like a `crystal prog.cr -- PROG_ENV=production`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just set environment variables in your shell like for any other program and they will be available in the Crystal compiler. For example  `PROG_ENV=production crystal prog.cr`